# Crystal report RPT file is there a way to view the code behind?

Tags: crystal-reports

In SSRS RDL file you can right click in Visual studio and click view code. there you can see any VB code that may apply, any grouping , formula ect.

Is there a similar action in Crystal report RPT file?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

The crystal desktop client lets you edit the .rpt file and see the code.

You can also use RptToXml on GitHub to convert .rpt to .xml

The xml will contain code that will help explain how a report was constructed.